# Reduce Hard disk size using Gparted in VMWare player?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, gparted, vmware

When using Ubuntu 12.04, i increased Hard disk size from 150GB to 300GB manually in VM player by mistake.(VM ware located in D:/ drive, which is 232GB in size).

However, I couldn't see 300GB replicated in Ubuntu(was not knowing that i should use Gparted to increase partition from 150GB to 300GB).

Is it possible to reduce 300GB to 150GB using Gparted in VMWare player? (150GB is still unallocated out of 300GB)[GParted details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9bIz.png)

Comment: Could you please update your question with a screen dump of the disk in gparted ?

Comment: I'm unable to attach image, so please click on GParted details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to reduce 300GB to 150GB using Gparted in VMWare
>   player? (150GB is still unallocated out of 300GB)

GParted is able to grow and shrink many different file systems and other formats - see [GParted Features](http://gparted.org/features.php).  However, GParted is not able to grow or shrink the size of a hard disk drive.

In the post you stated that you grew the size of the hard disk drive with VMware Player.

You might check to see if there is an option to shrink the size of a hard disk drive with VMware Player.